# How to get repository tags via RefService

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, bitbucket, hook

I am not Java developer at all. But I've expected it shouldn't be that hard. I am trying to put the specific plugin for Bitbucket Server, which will trigger postReceive and will check for a specific tag and then perform the basic action (publish contents of committed files via REST). The simplified code example below and it doesn't work.

```
public class ReleaseNotesHook implements AsyncPostReceiveRepositoryHook, RepositorySettingsValidator
{
private static final PageRequestImpl PAGE_REQUEST = new PageRequestImpl(0, 100);
private RefService refService;

public ReleaseNotesHook(RefService refService){
    this.refService = refService;
}

public void postReceive(RepositoryHookContext context, Collection<RefChange> refChanges)
{
    String url = context.getSettings().getString("url");



    for (RefChange refCh : refChanges) {
        boolean isAdd = (refCh.getType() == RefChangeType.ADD);
        boolean isTag = (refCh.getRef().getId().contains("tags"));
        if (isAdd && isTag) {
            Repository repo = context.getRepository();
            RepositoryTagsRequest tagRequest = new RepositoryTagsRequest.Builder(repo).build();
            Page<Tag> tags = refService.getTags(tagRequest, PAGE_REQUEST);
            performSomething(tags);
        }
    }
}

} //class
```

When I launch atlas-debug it builds project fine and starts Bitbucket Server, but fails to plug in hook with error:

[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.atlassian.bitbucket.plugin.releasenotes.hook.ReleaseNotesHook': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.atlassian.bitbucket.repository.RefService]: : No qualifying bean of type [com.atlassian.bitbucket.repository.RefService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.atlassian.bitbucket.repository.RefService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

My main resources for this plugin are:

- https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/01/beer-o-clock-stash-plugin-tutorial/
- https://developer.atlassian.com/static/javadoc/bitbucket-server/4.6.2/api/reference/com/atlassian/bitbucket/repository
- https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/stash-example-hook-protect-ref/commits/a38e6118b0b1ac1b9b73959e32325271d3d3937a?at=update-example-for-bitbucket-rebrand#chg-src/main/java/com/atlassian/bitbucket/server/repository/hook/ref/RefValidator.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is XML file that requires to be edited. It contains all dependency annotations. I don't have access to source code anymore, so I cannot recall file name, but I remember that editing it helped me and allowed to use all *Service handlers I needed.